# Site is down and admin log in is broken

Tags: admin-login, varien

I am stuck here.
My Magento site is just a blank white screen, and the admin panel log in has three fields and no log in button.

I have attached an image of the admin log in and also the error I saw

Can anyone help? I am really struggling!
Thanks[image][image]

Comment: Did you make any changes leading up to this? e.g. changing of any configuration options in Magento admin?

Comment: I am finding out now, will answer asap

Comment: Reply from the user: 'No we wasn't adding anything, but Fasthosts had sent us an e-mail last month about back ups being deleted as they were holding too much for us.  I am wondering if it could have anything to do with this?'

Comment: try deleting all files from var/cache e.g `rm -rf var/cache/*` in console

Comment: I am deleting all files in htdocs/var/cache

Comment: I have a cache12 and a cache123 folder as well, should I delete those?

Comment: Deleting the cache fixed the site, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Fix: Delete cache folder contents. `MAGE_DIRECTORY/var/cache/`

"This error appears when a corruption in the cache arises, caused by a bug in Magento.
We see this error mosty on shops that experience high traffic, causing a race condition in the caching mechanism."

source and workaround: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/magento-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-error/

Comment: I am deleting the cache now, I also have cache12 and cache123 am I OK to delete those? Thanks

Comment: Magento will only write to var/cache/ , it sounds like an ex-developer has renamed the 'cache' folder via FTP to save deleting? (As deleting via FTP will be slow)

Comment: OK deleting the cache fixed the site, thank you! The cache12 and cache123 folders seem to be duplicates of what was in cache, or very very similar, am I ok to delete those?

Comment: Should be OK, yes. But sounds like a recurring issue from what you've just told me, so may be a good idea to advise the website owners of the article I quoted :)

Comment: Will do thank you, something is filling the cache for sure, really appreciate your help thank you so much. Magento is not familiar to me so this is a massive help

Comment: No problem - I'd be most grateful if you could accept my answer as the solution